# Task Scheduler runs python.exe script but not pythonw.exe

Tags: python

Tried to schedule the launch of a script with the help of Task Scheduler so it runs daily / every 5 minutes. I'm out of solutions as to why my script seems to run fine when setting it up with python.exe but doesn't with pythonw.exe (silent).

I get this error code

```
Task Scheduler successfully completed task "\Automation\New Ads" , instance "{#######}" , action "C:\Users\#####\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\pythonw.exe" with return code 2147942401.
```

I've got no idea and can't seem to find a solution online.

Having a terminal pop every 5 minutes is annoying. That's the reason I'm looking at running it with pythonw.exe.

Comment: Can you share your script itself?

Comment: I'll share it with you in the morning. It's a pretty complex script.

Comment: Here's us the script. https://github.com/CRutkowski/Kijiji-Scraper